# Configure VB.net desktop application to work with Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable x64 bit version

Tags: excel, vb.net, import

I have an application that import data from excel to DataGridView.

```
Private Sub btnEditClass_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditClass.Click
    Dim pathofExcel As String
    Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    pathofExcel = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathofExcel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet

    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        MyConnection.Open()

        Try
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    End If
End Sub
```

With this to work, I installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.

[image]

My application, before publishing, I ensure that it works on AnyCPU. For this import to work, I need to make sure that AccessDatabaseEngine.exe (which is the 32bit version) is installed otherwise if I install AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe, it won't work and would say "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.".

The problem is, when i install the 32 bit version, cpmputer (with windows 10) won't accept it because the MS office installed is 64 bit. I need to uninstall 64 bit office and install 32 bit for the AccessDatabaseEngine to be installed.

My question is, is there a way I can configure my application to accept AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 so that computer running MS Office 64 bit won't have any problem?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have Office x64 installed, `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` x64 is already there. If you want to use the 32bit driver, you can install `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` x86 version.

Comment: The pc has Microsoft office 2016 professional 64bit version. When I install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 x64, it does not get error but my application use for importing does not work. it says "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.".. so I had to uninstall it and install 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' x86 but the computer says , I cannot install 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'  x86 because I have 64 bit MS office.

Comment: If you have `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` x64 and you app bitness is 32Bit, then it cannot find the driver. You can: - build your app with the `AnyCPU` profile and deselect `Prefer 32-bit` in the Build panel (so you can use the existing x64 driver). - Install the 32 bit version of the `ACE.OLEDB.` **16** `.0` driver.

Comment: There is no way that one build of your app can support every scenario. The answer is to build your project twice. For one build, select `Any CPU` and check `Prefer 32-bit`. For the second build, select `x64`. Use the second build for 64-bit Office and the first build everywhere else. If there are two options for ACE, why can't there be two options for your app?